# BeautifulSoup - how to get the second next item in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<div _ngcontent-c2=""><span _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-secondary">Claim date: </span><span _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-primary">26 September, 2018</span></div>
```

I want to find the `26 September, 2018` text from above after finding the `Claim date:`.

I have tried `findNext`, `find_next_sibling` and a lot of other suggestions.

There are multiple `_ngcontent2` and `text-primary`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex.Import re. and then find the text of the span tag and then find_next span tag.

```
import re
html='''<div _ngcontent-c2=""><span _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-secondary">Claim date: </span><span _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-primary">26 September, 2018</span></div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span',text=re.compile('Claim date:')).find_next('span').text)
```

Output:

```
26 September, 2018
```

OR if you have **bs4 4.7.1** or above you can use css selector.

```
html='''<div _ngcontent-c2=""><span _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-secondary">Claim date: </span><span _ngcontent-c2="" class="text-primary">26 September, 2018</span></div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('span:contains("Claim date:")').find_next('span').text)
```